# Get correct link to category - Wordpress - Genesis - News theme

Tags: wordpress

```
if ( $cat ) echo '<a class="custom-cat-btn" href="#cat-' . $cat . '">More ' . get_cat_name($cat) . ' Posts</a>';
```

This gives me:
http://mydomain.com/#cat-127

But I get a 404 when I click on the link

Can anyone help me get the actual link please

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the category link with [get_category_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link)

So,

```
if ( $cat ) echo '<a class="custom-cat-btn" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $cat ) ) . '">More ' . get_cat_name($cat) . ' Posts</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, but I think I am missing something.. I used that code and now I get code in the address bar: http://example.com/%3C?php%20echo%20esc_url(%20get_category_link(%20$cat%20)%20);%20?%3E

Comment: if ( $cat ) echo '<a class="custom-cat-btn" href="?cat=' . $cat . '">More ' . get_cat_name($cat) . ' Posts</a>';

this seems to work for me.. gives me a url = example.com?cat=127

not sure if that is 100% right? but it works, is ?cat= the current standard?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I truly am half asleep, silly syntax error :), try that edit.

Comment: Thanks, I dont have enough rep to close or vote up, sorry.. But this has been answered now

Comment: You can mark it as answered though - click the tick to the left to make it go green.